# Exception when using validates_timeliness gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I get the following exception frequently since starting to use the validates_timeliness gem

```
    Message undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
    Location    /client_issue/create?client_id=15285
    Action  create
    Controller  client_issue
    Query   client_id=15285
    Method  POST
    SSL true
```

The exception happens if somebody enters a date such as 28 Sept 2012. If they use a correct three letter month (ie. 28 Sep 2012) there is no problem.
In fact any invalid month name will cause the exception for example 28 bjhg 2012.

Heres's the top of the stacktrace

```
    /shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/timeliness-0.3.6/lib/timeliness/parser.rb:142:in `fast_date_valid_with_fallback'
    /shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/timeliness-0.3.6/lib/timeliness/parser.rb:24:in `make_time'
    /shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/timeliness-0.3.6/lib/timeliness/parser.rb:17:in `parse'
    /shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/validates_timeliness-3.0.14/lib/validates_timeliness/attribute_methods.rb:49:in `start_date='
    /shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:85:in `send'
    /shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:85:in `assign_attributes'
```

The relevant bit of my model model looks like this:

```
    class ClientIssue < PauaServiceTable
      validates_date :start_date ,:allow_blank => true 
       ...
    end
```

My initializer for the gem has the following in it:

```
    config.restriction_shorthand_symbols.update(
      :now   => lambda { Time.current },
      :today => lambda { Date.current }
     )
     config.parser.remove_formats(:date, 'm/d/yy')
     config.parser.remove_us_formats
     config.parser.use_euro_formats
```

I cant see why I'm getting exceptions. I should be able to pass any old rubbish and just get an invalid date message, not an exception.
Have I got something setup wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be an issue with the timeliness gem.
see answer to my issue [here](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness/issues/84)

However since any incorrect month name causes the exception (eg 28 sap 2012) will throw an exception as well. I have decided to do manual validation of dates as otherwise my users will be experiencing exceptions all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You are using both `validates_timeliness` gem, which provides the `validates_date` method, and `timeliness` gem, which raises the error.

You'd probably use either, not both.